# PowerBI Embedded vertical scrollbar not visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have embedded a PowerBI report. This is the Javascript with the page setup.

For some reason I don't get a vertical scrollbar in my report. When I open it in the workspace online the scrollbars work just fine. I already tried switching between different 'View' options in PowerBi but that does not seem to make a difference.

```
<H2>PowerBI</H2>
<p><i>User: {{username}} | AccessLevel: {{access_level}}</i></p>
<div id="reportContainer" style="height: 80vh;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
 
// Get models. models contains enums that can be used.
var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

var embedConfiguration = {
    type: 'report',
    id: '{{txtembedreportid}}',
    embedUrl: '{{txtreportembed}}',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: '{{txtaccesstoken}}',
    settings: {
            layoutType: models.LayoutType.Custom,
            customLayout: {
                pageSize: {
                    type: models.PageSizeType.Widescreen,
                }
            },
            panes:{
                bookmarks: {
                    visible: false
                },
                fields: {
                    expanded: false
                },
                filters: {
                    expanded: false,
                    visible: false
                },
                pageNavigation: {
                    visible: true
                },
                selection: {
                    visible: true
                },
                syncSlicers: {
                    visible: true
                },
                visualizations: {
                    expanded: false
                }
           }
    }
};

var $reportContainer = $('#reportContainer');
var report = powerbi.embed($reportContainer.get(0), embedConfiguration);
report.fullscreen(); 
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the "displayOption" property with value "FitToWidth" in customLayout object, as this option will try to fit the report as per the total available size for the page and will introduce a scrollbar for the remaining part if necessary.

Also change "Widescreen" to "Custom" in pageSizeType object

After all changes, your embedConfiguration will become as following.

```js
var embedConfiguration = {
    type: 'report',
    id: '{{txtembedreportid}}',
    embedUrl: '{{txtreportembed}}',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: '{{txtaccesstoken}}',
    settings: {
            layoutType: models.LayoutType.Custom,
            customLayout: {
                displayOption: models.DisplayOption.FitToWidth, // Add "FitToWidth"
                pageSize: {
                    type: models.PageSizeType.Custom, // Change to "Custom"
                }
            },
            panes:{
                bookmarks: {
                    visible: false
                },
                fields: {
                    expanded: false
                },
                filters: {
                    expanded: false,
                    visible: false
                },
                pageNavigation: {
                    visible: true
                },
                selection: {
                    visible: true
                },
                syncSlicers: {
                    visible: true
                },
                visualizations: {
                    expanded: false
                }
           }
    }
};
```

Refer docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/custom-layout